# UI Unity error: The requested operation caused a stack overflow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I made this test GUI that shows a game over display when the spotlight of enemy reachs you. but when it happens Unity crashed and noticed the error

```
StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
```

Here's my code that's crashing:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class GameUI : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameLoseUI;
   // public GameObject playerDiedUI;
    //public GameObject noEnergyUI;
    bool gameIsOver;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Guard.OnGuardHasSpottedPlayer += ShowGameLoseUI;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        /*if (gameIsOver)
        {if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            }
        }*/     
    }

    void ShowGameLoseUI()
    {
        OnGameOver(gameLoseUI);
    }

    void OnGameOver(GameObject gameoverUI)
    {
        gameLoseUI.SetActive(true);
        gameIsOver = true;
        Guard.OnGuardHasSpottedPlayer += ShowGameLoseUI;
    }
}
```

I thought the error might be within the void Update but unity keeps crashing even with this commented snippet. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Should that last line have a - instead of a+? Actually why do you have that last line? You've already signed up for the event.

Comment: Does the exception mention on which line in the code it is thrown?

Comment: @palebone if him delete the last line ll still working? how?

Comment: @palebone i remove the last line and still working!! no idea how but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the Comments, you are infinitely subscribing to `Guard.OnGuardHasSpottedPlayer` when you GameOver, which causes the exception.

Change the `+=` to `-=`

```
void OnGameOver(GameObject gameoverUI)
    {
        gameLoseUI.SetActive(true);
        gameIsOver = true;
        Guard.OnGuardHasSpottedPlayer -= ShowGameLoseUI;
    }
```